# Preprocessing for Resnet50 Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, validation, keras, nan, resnet

I am using  `ImageDataGenerator()` and passing `tf.keras.applications.preprocessing.resnet50` as the `preprocessing` argument for `ImageDataGenerator()`.

The original image values are between 0-255. But after the preprocessing, I noticed that the image values are not between 0-1 and I get `val_loss: nan`. My activation functions are `selu` and `softmax.`

[Image data value after preprocessing using tf.keras.applications.preprocessing.resnet50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zetEn.png)

My questions are is `tf.keras.applications.preprocessing.resnet50` suppose normalize the data between 0-1?

Am I potentially getting `val_loss: nan` because my data is not scaled between 0-1?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import PIL
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

def ds_generator(h, w, bs, preprocessing):
    
    train_folder = '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/PCM_Map_Images/train/'
    test_folder = '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/PCM_Map_Images/test/'
    dir_train = pathlib.Path(train_folder)
    dir_test = pathlib.Path(test_folder)

    data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocessing, validation_split=0.15)

    train_ds = data_gen.flow_from_directory(dir_train, target_size=(h, w), class_mode='sparse', 
                                          subset='training', shuffle = False, 
                                          seed = 0, batch_size=bs)

    val_ds = data_gen.flow_from_directory(dir_train, target_size=(h, w), class_mode='sparse', 
                                        subset='validation', shuffle = False, 
                                        seed = 0, batch_size=bs)

    test_ds = data_gen.flow_from_directory('.', target_size=(h, w), class_mode=None, classes=['test'], shuffle=False,
                                           batch_size=bs)

    return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds 

resnet50 = tf.keras.applications.resnet50
h, w, c = 32, 32, 3
batch_size = 64
train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = ds_generator(h, w, batch_size, preprocessing=resnet50.preprocess_input)

model = Sequential()
Init = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(seed=0) # seed all that you can
cb = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', restore_best_weights=True, patience=6)


# you execute this line of code if NG made life easier

pre_train_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False,
                          input_shape=(h, w, c),
                          pooling='max',
                          weights='resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')

for layer in pre_train_model.layers[:-25]:
    if isinstance(layer, layers.BatchNormalization):
        layer.trainable = False
    else:
        layer.trainable = True

model.add(pre_train_model)
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='selu', kernel_initializer=Init))
model.add(Dropout(.50))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='selu', kernel_initializer=Init))
model.add(Dropout(.30))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=Init))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=0.01, clipnorm=1.0, beta_1=.01), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=6, validation_data=val_ds)
```

Comment: No, that wouldn't be an actual issue to get nan loss. Please provide reproducible code. Don't share screenshots, copy-paste the error log.

Answer (score 0):

The NaN is not due to the scaling. Most preprocess functions scale the image pixels between -1 and +1. You can use the code below as a preprocessor function

```
def preprocess(img)
 return img=img/127.5-1
```

then in ImageDataGenerator use

```
gen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator( preprocessing_function=preprocess)
```

Comment: Hi gerry, thanks for the feedback. I have put my code in the question. do you know why I am getting val_loss: nan? if Nan does not depend on scaling?